# # significant figures in calculations?

Tags: error-analysis

I was taught to use the same number of [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) in my answer as the piece of data with the lowest number of significant figures, so I was a bit confused when the solutions manual for this problem stated the answer as 2.45ms^-2.

Problem: The acceleration due to gravity at the earth's surface is 9.8ms-2. Calculate the acceleration due to gravity on a planet which has the same mass and twice the radius as the earth.

Here the piece of data with the lowest number of significant figures is 9.8ms-2 (2 sig fig), so shouldn't the answer be 2.5ms-2 and not 2.45ms-2 ?

Comment: So what if the person providing that answer simply wasn't following that rule?

Comment: @Name: But they state it at the start of their book!

Comment: Ohm stated a law of constant electrical resistance, but as a human he did not have a constant resistance himself. People don't always follow their own rules. =)

Comment: @Name Haha good one, but I can't resist (pun intended) pointing out that Ohm's law applies to a very special situation, whereas the rule given in the book is said to apply to "any physics calculation"

Comment: More on [significant figures](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error arises from the fact that it is common to use $$9.80 m/s^2$$ Perhaps this is what was meant.

Comment: So as it is stated in the book (i.e. "9.8ms-2") does it mean the answer should be "2.5ms-2"? Thanks

Comment: @user45220 yes, you should have been right